# Similarity Matrix chart js plugin?

Tags: javascript

I want to draw a self-similarity matrix based on data points, I'm wondering if there is a JavaScript plugin to render it, similar to xy.js or chart.js

this chart should look like:
[image: https://manuel.moussallam.net/PyMP/pyplots/build_sim_matrix.hires.png]

searching google keeps giving me results using D3 or cubism which seem to target realtime data flow, while I only have a single list of numbers that does not change.

Comment: https://plot.ly/javascript/2D-Histogram/

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to find an answer, so I made my own (so plugins still appreciated)

```
(function(w){

    function extend (target, source) {
        target = target || {};
        for (var prop in source) {
            if (typeof source[prop] === 'object') {
                target[prop] = extend(target[prop], source[prop]);
            } else {
                target[prop] = source[prop];
            }
        }
        return target;
    }

    w.Squares = function(ctx, options){

        var default_opts = {
        };
        options = extend(default_opts, options);

        if(!this instanceof Squares){
            return new Squares(ctx, options);
        }
        var amount = 0;
        this.draw = function(data){

            var max_x = 0, max_y = 0, max_z = 0;

            // count the number of data points
            data.forEach(function(row, x){
                if(x+1 > max_x) {
                    max_x = x+1;
                }
                row.forEach(function(val, y){
                    if(y+1 > max_y) {
                        max_y = y+1;
                    }
                    if(val > max_z) {
                        max_z = val;
                    }
                });
            });

            var w = parseInt(ctx.canvas.width / max_x, 10);
            var h = parseInt(ctx.canvas.height / max_y, 10);

            if(w>0 && h>0) {
                // draw the graph
                data.forEach(function (row, x) {
                    row.forEach(function (val, y) {
                        amount = parseInt(val / max_z * 255, 10);
                        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + parseInt(amount / 1.5, 10) + "," + parseInt(amount / 1.5, 10) + "," + amount + ")";
                        ctx.fillRect(x * w, y * h, w, h);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    };

})(window);
```

How to use

html:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="900" height="900"></canvas>

<script>
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
    if(!data[i]){
        data[i] = [];
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j ++) {
        data[i][j] = Math.random();
    }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var sqr = new Squares(ctx, {});
sqr.draw(data);
</script>
```

it looks like this

[image]